# Toolbar with custom layout: empty space on left side

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, androidx

I'm trying to add a customized toolbar to my app. This is the layout:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LOGO"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

but there's a sort of gap (the pink one) between toolbar left border and ConstraintLayout start border [image]

how can i remove it?

Comment: Add `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` in your `Toolbar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `contentInsetStart="0dp"`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LOGO"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```